# How to convert all SVG images to PNG images in an EPUB file

Tags: epub, conversion, svg

Is there a way to convert all of the SVG images in an EPUB file into PNG images? I want to do this because few EPUB readers have full support for SVG (most readers only implement a subset of SVG).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do it manually? Unzip the epub,  use a graphics program to convert the SVG files to png or jpg, change the HTML references and the file references in the package.opf file. Then zip up, rename the .zip file to .epub, validate and then you're done.

I know of no script or utility to do the conversions, but it can't be hard.

By the way, I inserted my first svg graphic in a kindle-bound epub, and everything rendered no problem. I honestly have no idea whether Adobe or Google Play reader supports it. Will report back in a few days with the results of that.

Comment: It is not feasible to do this manually because there are about 2500 SVG figures within the EPUB file in question.